# How join tables in multiple folders with Advantage Database Server

Tags: advantage-database-server

Using Advantage Database Server SQL, I need to be able to join free tables that are in separate folders.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't have direct experience with Advantage, but details would help.  Based on the other tags, it supports ANSI-92 join syntax...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With free tables you can specify relative paths to the tables in the FROM clause.

SELECT * FROM "..\directory1\table1.adt" a, "directory2\table2.adt" b WHERE a.ID = b.ID;

This [entry](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage10/index.html?master_using_table_names_with_paths.htm) in the help files describes the basics of it.

Comment: This is helpful, but I get an error because I have the AdsConnection set to have a connectpath, and it appears to prepend that information to the relative path. Is there a way to format the AdsConnection.connectPath so that it does not interfere?

Comment: You can give a full UNC path to the file \\server\share\path\to\table\ instead. I would strongly recommend looking into using relative paths if possible.  This makes deploying to different operating systems easier.